# Why will Qt not create a text file when running or debugging from inside Qt, but will create it when directly from the debug folder?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qfile, qtextstream

I am creating then writing to a text file using QTextStream.  The problem is that the file is created if I build the application and run it from folder it creates, but if I run it from inside Qt in either release or debug mode it doesn't create the file.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  I am using a Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably used a relative path, and inside QtCreator the "current directory" from where the executable is ran is not necessarily the directory where the executable is.

Try:

```
qDebug() << QDir::currentPath();
```

It will tell you where you should expect your file to be written.

Comment: Thank you.  The current path was in this weird hidden place, so I just changed it to an absolute path.